# CSS basic template issues

Tags: html, css

in my website there is 3 vital parts

1. Top Bar (must remain in the top, not fixed, 40px height, 100% width)
2. Timeline this is always floating left to the main area, the timeline is not re sizable, it is neutral in size
3. main area re sizes with the window it is Horizontally scrolled so it can be small width as long as you can still keep scrolling right/left

here is my progress so far......

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLJXp/embedded/result/)

**My issues:**

1. the top bar child elements are not aligned. like those simple inputs/text is at the bottom of the topbar and part of it is hidden, this doesnt happen with the image removed?? i need the top bar to always keep elements inline vertically centered and never resize in height
2. i cant get timeline and main area to take up the remaining height, i have them at 800px because nothing was working.

`width: 100%;
    height: 100% !important;
    margin: 0px;`

Answer (score 0):

I added a padding and checked your fiddle it looks much better. Is it this what you are after?

```
.top_bar
{
    z-index:100;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    max-height:40px !important;
    background-color:#ffff00;
    color:black;
    padding:40px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DLJXp/light/ I'm not too sure about that timeline issue I need to play around with it a bit more.

Comment: no, i need that topbar to be a normal bar, no such thing as scrolling on the top bar should be allowed like facebook.

Comment: if you remove the img from the topbar, everything is aligned, is the img that is messing up

Comment: so you do not want a fixed top bar correct? Let me see the CSS for the image. it think it needs to be placed in its own div

Comment: @ChouOne im starting to think its a vertical issue, so the inputs are trying to alight in the middle of the img, so if the img is 40 px just like the top bar is also 40px so the next elements will be at the middle of 40 px and start displaying below 20 px?

Comment: i fixed by simply adding  `vertical-align: bottom; ` to the img, now im trying to fill up, so i guess there is something i need to learn about vertical aligning

Answer (score 0):

For your top bar just float your image:

```
.wtblogo {
    float:left; /* Add this to your current CSS */
}
```

and add a line height equal to your top bars height to vertically align objects with in it:

```
.top_bar {
    line-height: 40px; /* Add this to your current CSS */
}
```

I am not sure what you mean for your second issue.

Answer (score 0):

For #1 you can easily fix it by adding:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

to your image class.

So you'll have:

```
.wtblogo {
    height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

For #2, I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Could you clarify?